# event calling multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In fusion chart once i click legend then if i click drilldown point means click event is calling multiple times because of this multiple drilldown popup is showing...

#### Directive

```js
angular
  .module("rootApp")
  .directive('fchart', function(chartExportService, $timeout, $uibModal, chartDrillDownService, appNotifyService) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
          cid: '@',
          dataformat: '@',
          width: '@',
          height: '@',
          dataSource: '@',
          type: '@',
          charts: '=',
          control: '=',
          data: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.internalControl = scope.control || {};

          var chart = null;
          var exportList = [];
          var agentData = {};
          scope.actionAfterExport = 'print';

          var chartConfigObject = {
            type: scope.type,
            width: scope.width,
            height: scope.height,
            renderAt: element[0],
            id: scope.cid,
            dataFormat: scope.dataformat || 'json',
            dataSource: attrs.datasource,
            events: {
              "beforeExport": function(evtObj, argObj) {
                var exportStatus = document.getElementById('chart-export-status');
                if (exportStatus) {
                  exportStatus.style.display = 'inline';
                }
              },
              "exported": function(eventObj, dataObj) {
                var exportStatus = document.getElementById('chart-export-status');
                if (exportStatus) {
                  exportStatus.style.display = 'none';
                }
              },
              "dataplotclick": function(ev, props) {


              }
            }
          };

          // Register methods for chart drill down calls from fusion chart
          // As fusion chart look for those methods in window scope, these
          // functions needs to be registered in window scope

          window.chartDrillDown = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillDown('chartDrillDown', info);
          };

          window.popupforTop10StnAndFisPCharts = function(info) {
            var test = true;
            if (test) {
              chartDrillDownService.doDrillDownFisPChart('popupforTop10StnAndFisPCharts', info);
            }
            test = false;
          };

          window.activityCountJs = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillDown('activityCountJs', info);
          };

          window.chartPopUpForTop10ByStationCharts = function(info) {

            chartDrillDownService.doDrillDownFisPChart('chartPopUpForTop10ByStationCharts', info);
          };

          window.chartDrillDownForLabels = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doTreeDrillDown('chartDrillDownForLabels', info);
          };

          window.Reveal = {};
          window.Reveal.PlantView = {
            DrillHandler: {}
          };
          window.Reveal.Compare = {
            DrillHandler: {}
          };

          window.Reveal.PlantView.DrillHandler.PopupActivity = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillDown('PlantView-PopupActivity', info);
          };

          window.Reveal.PlantView.DrillHandler.DrillActivity = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillDown('PlantView-DrillActivity', info);
          };

          window.Reveal.Compare.DrillHandler.DrillHours = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillHours('Compare-DrillHours', info);
          };

          window.Reveal.Compare.DrillHandler.DrillWeekly = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillWeekly('Compare-DrillWeekly', info);
          };

          window.Reveal.Compare.DrillHandler.DrillDay = function(info) {
            chartDrillDownService.doDrillDay('Compare-DrillDay', info);
          };

          var createFCChart = function() {
            // dispose if previous chart exists
            if (chart && chart.dispose) {
              chart.dispose();
            }

            // Setting to make FusionCharts rendering properly when <base> tag included in HTML head 
            FusionCharts.options.SVGDefinitionURL = 'absolute';

            chart = new FusionCharts(chartConfigObject);

            /* @todo validate the ready function whether it can be replaced in a better way */
            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
              element.ready(function() {
                // Render the chart only when angular is done compiling the element and DOM.
                chart.showBorder = 0;
                chart = chart.render();
                chart.uniqueId = scope.data || null;

                if (scope.charts) {
                  scope.charts.push(chart);
                }
              });
            });
          };
        };
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The event may be getting called by multiple targets in the DOM hierarchy. Validate this by using console.log'ing out the current target of the event. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

If that is the case, then one method to stop this is to call stopPropagation() on the event. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

The commented lines could be uncommented to test your situation:

```
"beforeExport": function(evtObj, argObj) {
// console.log(evtObj.currentTarget);
var exportStatus = document.getElementById('chart-export-status');
if (exportStatus) {
    exportStatus.style.display = 'inline';
}
//evtObj.stopPropagation();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to your problem.

```
Event.stopPropagation()
```

Read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

### option 1

Create another `$scope` variable that stores the state of the legend visibility. Something similar to the CSS Checkbox Hack. Then use the `ng-if` or `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives to show/hide a premade DOM element based on the value of `$scope` variable.

### option 2

Whatever code that you have that generates the `drilldown popup`, remove it from the angular directive/expression and place it in an external function. Have this function check if it has recently shown a popup,

- if it has: don't show the popup
- if it has not: do show the popup

## Explanation

I have also noticed this behavior. It is caused by the angular engine making multiple passes though the DOM looking for expressions that it needs to evaluate. <strike>**I don't know exactly**, but these stages probably go like this:</strike>

1. deep search: identify all the expressions exist and flag them
2. evaluate: loop over the flags and actually evaluate the expressions

If your expressions are inside `ng-repeat` blocks, then this effect is going to have a much greater effect than without.

I have found a source that explains this very well: [sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/#how-many-times-does-the-digest-loop-run).
The effect is caused by a dirty form of data checking. Angular runs through the DOM evaluating expressions and performing actions. Then, it runs through it again to make sure that all of the data is bound correctly. If the data is still not up-to-speed (maybe one of your functions changed a value), then it will keep going through the DOM until everything is in sync.

Disclaimer: I haven't used Fusion Charts.
But, I still have lots of code experience and I would recommend moving any code that generates modal boxes out (into a function that can use more complex logic to check whether or not to actually run).

In my opinion on modals, you should not be generating popup boxes inside Angular expressions. Modals should be used to show *benchmark* steps (like an error or a success).

Comment: we need prevent multiple dialog boxes from clint end by keeping some flag.       this is directive        window.popupforTop10StnAndFisPCharts = function(info) {
                
                if(!window.popupforTop10StnAndFisPChartsStatus){   //prventing multiple event calling
                    chartDrillDownService.doDrillDownFisPChart('popupforTop10StnAndFisPCharts', info);
                    window.popupforTop10StnAndFisPChartsStatus = true;
                }
            };

Comment: $scope.resetFlag = function(){
        if (options.type == "popupforTop10StnAndFisPCharts")
        {
            //once ok/close button click it ill reset for avoiding multiple popup display
            window.popupforTop10StnAndFisPChartsStatus = false;
           
        }
        }; //controller

Comment: @swetha thanks for telling me its useful, I love to help other people. Can you please upvote my answer if that is how you feel?